Can print excel laravel directly in web?
I use excel laravel to print from view. I just found out option for download excel file not for print.
      return Excel::download(DocumentController::$ExcelList[$type_doc], 'ten-file.xlsx', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);    

So, Is it available? Thank you.
